# Cделать составную фигуру из треугольников со скругленными углами

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg, анимация

Помогите на css создать подобное оформление, а именно 2 треугольника с скругленными углами, (желательно с градиентом, но его я и сам  могу добавить)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как по мне, лучше использовать svg

Comment: Они еще и крутятся создавая иллюзию круга, если svg можно крутить, то ничего против не имею

Comment: в svg не шарю, но вроде она нормально "управляется" через css и\или js

Comment: @ДенисЛебедев треугольники вращаются вместе или каждый отдельно?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Каждый отдельно, но тут задача именно повторить форму хотяб одного треугольника

Comment: @ДенисЛебедев загляните сюда, через часок, два. Попробую сделать

Comment: @Alexandr_TT возможно упростит задачу http://plnkr.co/edit/kGnGGyoOCKil02k04snu?p=preview

Comment: @ДенисЛебедев Я полностью повторил ваш дизайн формы треугольников и сделал анимацию. Но дизайн надо менять, так как при вращении треугольников в разные стороны возникают пробелы. Смотрите замечания в конце моего ответа. Надеюсь, что вы сможете самостоятельно изменить форму кривых, опираясь на технику в моем ответе. В любом случае ответ дан - сделать треугольники со скругленными краями. Если ответ был вам полезен, не забудьте отметить его плюсом и галочкой.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Техника создания патчей кривых по образцу на картинке

- Вырезаем из картинки область, которая понадобится для создания патчей

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Картинка имеет размеры `830х764px`

- создаем файл svg для загрузки в векторный редактор.  Это необходимо
  для точного совпадения кривых с фоном и чтобы потом вёрстка не
  разъезжалась при изменении масштаба

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="830" height="764" viewBox="0 0 830 764" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="border:1px solid red;" >  

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OC0N.png" width="830" height="764" />
</svg>
```

- Определяем центр картинки, это будет центр вращения треугольников -
  `415х382`

  И с помощью инструмента - "Рисовать кривые Безье" наносим узловые
  точки по периметру кривых

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Сохраняем файл. Из него понадобятся два патча, которые и определяют
  контур фигур

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="75%" height="75%" viewBox="0 0 830 764" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" border="1">
 <path fill="dodgerblue" d="m106.4 291.3c69.2-122.8 231.6-189.7 349.7-191.7 116 3.6 207.5 27.1 238.6 141.4 7.7 46.4 12.8 66 10.7 158.3-1.9 83.4-58.3 198.2-109.2 249.2-98 102.5-194.6 77.1-280.4 27.5C268 647.5 221.3 614.3 185.4 571.7 114.7 478.2 64.8 381.2 106.4 291.3Z" >
  </path>
   <path fill="purple" d="m144.1 408c-1.7-118.1 42.1-167.9 101.2-225.1 38.6-37.4 102.8-61.6 148.9-61.5 68.2 0.1 139.1 14.9 188.6 58.3 63 55.2 108.1 109.2 105.2 228.4C683.9 575.4 533.4 669.2 414.3 666.9 281.5 664.3 146.2 558.6 144.1 408Z" />
  </svg>
```

### Маска, градиенты и анимация фигур

- Нам необходимо применить градиент к области между двумя контурами
  фигур. Поэтому вырезаем `маской` внутреннюю, бордовую  часть

К оставшейся части применяем градиент и анимируем вращение фигуры вокруг вычисленного ранее центра - `415х382`

`<animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 415 382;360 415 382" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite" />`

Ниже полный код вращения одного треугольника:

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="830" height="764" viewBox="0 0 830 764" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" border="1">
 <defs>
        <linearGradient id="redyel" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="rgba(127, 0, 221, 1)"/>   
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="rgba(88, 159, 179, 1)"/>   
        </linearGradient> 
   <mask id="ellips" >
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/> 
   <path fill="black" d="m144.1 408c-1.7-118.1 42.1-167.9 101.2-225.1 38.6-37.4 102.8-61.6 148.9-61.5 68.2 0.1 139.1 14.9 188.6 58.3 63 55.2 108.1 109.2 105.2 228.4C683.9 575.4 533.4 669.2 414.3 666.9 281.5 664.3 146.2 558.6 144.1 408Z" />
   </mask> 
 </defs>
<rect width="100%" height="100%" />
 <g>
 <path mask="url(#ellips)" fill="url(#redyel)" d="m106.4 291.3c69.2-122.8 231.6-189.7 349.7-191.7 116 3.6 207.5 27.1 238.6 141.4 7.7 46.4 12.8 66 10.7 158.3-1.9 83.4-58.3 198.2-109.2 249.2-98 102.5-194.6 77.1-280.4 27.5C268 647.5 221.3 614.3 185.4 571.7 114.7 478.2 64.8 381.2 106.4 291.3Z" >
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 415 382;360 415 382" dur="8s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path>
  
</g>
  </svg>
```

- Добавляем второй треугольник. Чтобы они вращались по разному, задаем
  задержку начала анимации для второго треугольника
  `begin="an1.begin+1s"` и задаем разную продолжительность вращения:
  `14s` и `16s`

### Полный код анимации двух треугольников

- Вращение треугольников в одну сторону

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="830" height="764" viewBox="0 0 830 764" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" border="1">
 <defs>
        <linearGradient id="blurey" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="rgba(126,1,218,1)"/>   
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="rgba(62,182,194, 1)"/>   
        </linearGradient>  
  <linearGradient id="greenrey" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="rgba(99,1,184,0.7)"/>   
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="rgba(3,200,170, 0.7)"/>   
        </linearGradient>
  
  <mask id="ellips" >
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/> 
   <path fill="black" d="m144.1 408c-1.7-118.1 42.1-167.9 101.2-225.1 38.6-37.4 102.8-61.6 148.9-61.5 68.2 0.1 139.1 14.9 188.6 58.3 63 55.2 108.1 109.2 105.2 228.4C683.9 575.4 533.4 669.2 414.3 666.9 281.5 664.3 146.2 558.6 144.1 408Z" />
   </mask> 
  <path id="Triangle" mask="url(#ellips)"  d="m106.4 291.3c69.2-122.8 231.6-189.7 349.7-191.7 116 3.6 207.5 27.1 238.6 141.4 7.7 46.4 12.8 66 10.7 158.3-1.9 83.4-58.3 198.2-109.2 249.2-98 102.5-194.6 77.1-280.4 27.5C268 647.5 221.3 614.3 185.4 571.7 114.7 478.2 64.8 381.2 106.4 291.3Z" >
 
  </path>
 </defs>
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
<g>
<use xlink:href="#Triangle" fill="url(#blurey)">
  <animateTransform id="an1"  attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 415 382;360 415 382"  dur="16s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
 </use>
 
 <use xlink:href="#Triangle"  fill="url(#greenrey)">
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 415 382;360 415 382" dur="14s" begin="an1.begin+1s" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
 </use>

</g>  

  </svg>
```

- Вращение треугольников в разные стороны

Если внимательно посмотреть на внутренние контуры треугольников, то они имеют  форму эллипса. Поэтому при взаимном вращении треугольников в разные стороны будут возникать прорези-пробелы на фон. Это понятно, ведь радиусы одного эллипса всегда различны.

Пробелы возникают, когда малый радиус одного эллипса накладывается на большой радиус другого эллипса.

Чтобы не было такого эффекта нужно делать внутренний бордюр треугольников круглым.

```css
.container {
width:75%;
height:75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" >
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"   viewBox="0 0 830 764" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
 <defs>
        <linearGradient id="blurey" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="rgba(126,1,218,1)"/>   
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="rgba(62,182,194, 1)"/>   
        </linearGradient>  
  <linearGradient id="greenrey" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="rgba(99,1,184,0.7)"/>   
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="rgba(3,200,170, 1)"/>   
        </linearGradient>
  
  <mask id="ellips" >
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/> 
   <path fill="black" d="m144.1 408c-1.7-118.1 42.1-167.9 101.2-225.1 38.6-37.4 102.8-61.6 148.9-61.5 68.2 0.1 139.1 14.9 188.6 58.3 63 55.2 108.1 109.2 105.2 228.4C683.9 575.4 533.4 669.2 414.3 666.9 281.5 664.3 146.2 558.6 144.1 408Z" />
   </mask> 
  <path id="Triangle" mask="url(#ellips)"  d="m106.4 291.3c69.2-122.8 231.6-189.7 349.7-191.7 116 3.6 207.5 27.1 238.6 141.4 7.7 46.4 12.8 66 10.7 158.3-1.9 83.4-58.3 198.2-109.2 249.2-98 102.5-194.6 77.1-280.4 27.5C268 647.5 221.3 614.3 185.4 571.7 114.7 478.2 64.8 381.2 106.4 291.3Z" >
 
  </path>
 </defs>
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
<g>
<use xlink:href="#Triangle" fill="url(#blurey)">
  <animateTransform id="an1"  attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 415 382;360 415 382"  dur="24s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
 </use>
 
 <use xlink:href="#Triangle"  fill="url(#greenrey)">
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 415 382;-360 415 382" dur="24s" begin="an1.begin" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
 </use>

</g>  

  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: я на смартфоне видел это .... там каждый треугольник крутится в разные стороны ... создаётся эффект как фотошопе делается наложение ...screen ....в общем аналогия blend-mode:screen что то типа того

Comment: @НикитаФаст можно и в разные стороны заставить вращаться треугольники, для этого надо лишь поменять угол на отриц. значение

Comment: @Alexandr_TT яб тебя расцеловал, спасибо :D

Comment: Как можно внутренний размер изменить? :D

Comment: @Alexandr_TT именно так выглядело .... + вам

Comment: Не сказал бы что это треугольники